# How to get params in controller slim 2

Tags: slim

I need to access the json object from the controller

This is my route (routes.php):

```
$app->post('/todo', 'App\Controller\ProductosController:testTodo');
```

and my controller (ProductosController.php):

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

class ProductosController
{       
    public function testTodo()
    {
        $data = $app->request->getBody();
        $data = json_decode($data);
        echo json_encode(array("status"=>true, "data"=>$data));        
    }
 }
```

Thanks..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get params in controller? I usually use $ app->request->getBody(); But in my case, separating the controller and the route doesn't work

Comment: Not enough information to help. Slim 2 or 3? What does the most simple index.php that shows the problem look like?